# Powershell: Rename the last integer to

Tags: powershell, move, batch-rename

At work we have to rename 150 files at a time.

I thought PowerShell would be the best way to get this done quickly. But I am having some difficulty. There is a requirement, that the files end with Lxx. The xx will be an incremental number increase from 1 - 12. Then loop back and start again for the next batch. My apologies as today is the best I could come up with.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TEST" -Recurse -Include "*.txt" | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Counter = 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -NewName $_.BaseName_+ "_$Counter" ; $Counter++}
```

Unfortunately, the loop is a requirement, as this allows it to be in the naming convention of the import code.

Or maybe do all of this and output it to separate folders containing 12, then rename?

Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: you state that you need "to rename 150 files at a time" at the beginning of your question but then you state that "The xx will be an incremental number increase from 1 - 12" so how these 2 things relate to each other? Your question is not clear imo

Comment: My apologies, this is my test bed at home. Still trying to figure it out. The tool we use will output in the above format. T1R1C1L1. The T stands for tray. it can do a number of trays at a time. It will always output in 12 files.  T1 will be Tray 1 and T2 will be Tray 2 up to 12 trays at a time. 150 is a rough estimate but exact would 144 possible files at a processing time. When we process a batch for review, it will be in its own folder whcih we cut and past every batch. Which is the 12 files. The next tool requires the file ending to be T1R1C1L1 to T1R1C1L01.

Comment: After the L it require the 2 digit format for the intiger.

Comment: So the question in simple terms is how you can rename the files using always 2 digits? If so you can use the `ToString('D2')` method on your counter

Comment: And is there a way to limit the counter to 12? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: `Select-Object -First 12` before renaming

Comment: Just to clarify, can you add the expected “before” and “after” file names to your question (not in a comment).